# How to change everything white in a design to a texture image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, clipping-mask

I have a design I'm updating and it seems the previous designer was able to replace everything set to white in the Illustrator file to show up with a kraft background instead: 
[image: first image of element with kraft background]

If you triple-click on any "kraft" element in the document you can see that it is white (and you can't click to "release clipping mask" because it isn't one: 
[image: element after you double click and see it's white]

It literally seems like anything in the document that is technically set to have a white background if you click on it, automatically gets a kraft background per the texture they use. I am wondering how they did this without clipping masks and how I can recreate - any demos on this? I wouldn't even know what to call it, hah!

Also checked layers and couldn't find this texture in it:
[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks so much for reading.

Comment: Kind of difficult to provide an answer without direct file examination.

Comment: Maybe the texture can be found in the `View > Links` panel?

Comment: Looks like it might be a transparency mask, rather than a clipping mask.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from your screen shot, but I suspect there might be a transparency mask, rather than a clipping mask.  In any case, I think transparency masks are the way to go to make something like this.

Here's an example below, showing a transparency mask applied to a group.  You can see if you expand your layers, you should be able to find a group which is underlined.  If you select it, and open up the Transparency window, you should be able to see if there is a mask applied.

[image]

You can then edit the mask by clicking on the mask thumbnail in the Transparency window.  To switch out of editing of the mask, select the group thumbnail in the Transparency window.

You can then copy and paste an image as the background texture and send it to the back of the layer stack, so that the mask cuts out the group revealing the background image underneath.

[image]